Request method IN PY Django
I am new to Django and python and I made a POST request from my HTML page. However, when I tried the request.method === "GET" to retrieve the data it did not work.
HTML
<form id="form" action="fd.py" method="post" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">            
            <div class="input-control">
                <div class="username">
                    <label for="username" class="label">Username</label>
                    <input id="usernameId" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username"

         autocomplete="username" maxlength="64">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="email">
                    <label class="lemail" for="email">Email</label>
                    <input id="emailId" name="email" type="text" placeholder="email">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="password">
                    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                    <input id="passwordId" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="repassword">
                    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                    <input id="repasswordId" name="repassword" type="password" placeholder="re-      
       confirm password"
      autocomplete="current-password">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                </div>
                <button id="nextButton" class="nextButton" type="submit"></button>
            </div>
        </form>

PY
from django.http import HttpRequest
     from django.contrib.auth import login, logout


    def FindRqst(request):
        if request.method == "GET":
            print("POST Request Found")
        else:
            print("POST Request Not Found :(")

If I have not imported the right module or have done something wrong please let me know.

What does "it did not work" mean?

Why use if request.method == "GET"? Shouldn't it be if request.method == 'POST':  since you made a post request from your HTML ?

Add csrf_Token in html file
registration.html
  <form id="form" action="fd.py" method="post" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
            {% csrf_token %}

    
            <div class="input-control">
                <div class="username">
                    <label for="username" class="label">Username</label>
                    <input id="usernameId" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username"

         autocomplete="username" maxlength="64">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="email">
                    <label class="lemail" for="email">Email</label>
                    <input id="emailId" name="email" type="text" placeholder="email">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="password">
                    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                    <input id="passwordId" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="repassword">
                    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                    <input id="repasswordId" name="repassword" type="password" placeholder="re-      
       confirm password"
      autocomplete="current-password">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                </div>
                <button id="nextButton" class="nextButton" type="submit"></button>
            </div>
</form>

Use post method instead of get in these FindRqst functions
views.py
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout


    def FindRqst(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
           username = request.POST["username"]
           email = request.POST["email"]
           password = request.POST["password"]
           password = request.POST["password"]

           if password == confirm_password:
              new_user = CustomUser(
                  username=username,
                  email=email,
                  password=password,
                  password=password,
                  )
              new_user.save()
              return redirect("login")

        return render(request, "registration.html")

